# Redshift SQL Window Function number of rows before 120 days

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have an invoice table that looks

| invoice_id | account_id | date_issued |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 19/03/2020 |
| 6 | 1 | 7/04/2020 |
| 41 | 1 | 9/04/2020 |
| 27 | 1 | 17/04/2020 |
| 16 | 1 | 19/04/2020 |
| 32 | 1 | 19/07/2020 |
| 9 | 1 | 22/07/2020 |
| 48 | 1 | 5/08/2020 |
| 19 | 1 | 10/08/2020 |
| 11 | 1 | 13/08/2020 |
| 39 | 1 | 13/08/2020 |
| 35 | 1 | 19/08/2020 |
| 40 | 1 | 21/08/2020 |
| 25 | 1 | 23/08/2020 |

I need to insert a column which gives number of invoices that are 120 days or older for the set invoice and date (poulate in the same row). The result looks like as follows

| invoice_id | account_id | date_issued | no of invoices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 19/03/2020 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 7/04/2020 | 0 |
| 41 | 1 | 9/04/2020 | 0 |
| 27 | 1 | 17/04/2020 | 0 |
| 16 | 1 | 19/04/2020 | 0 |
| 32 | 1 | 19/07/2020 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 22/07/2020 | 1 |
| 48 | 1 | 5/08/2020 | 2 |
| 19 | 1 | 10/08/2020 | 3 |
| 11 | 1 | 13/08/2020 | 3 |
| 39 | 1 | 13/08/2020 | 3 |
| 35 | 1 | 19/08/2020 | 4 |
| 40 | 1 | 21/08/2020 | 5 |
| 25 | 1 | 23/08/2020 | 6 |

Can anyone help with window function?

I have tried and didnt work

```
select
    invoice_id,
    account_id,
    date_issued,
    count(invoice_id) OVER(PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY date_issued rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as invoices
from temp.r_invoices
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Redshift does not support the `range` window frame specification.  So you cannot do this in Redshift using window functions -- and that is the specific question you are asking.  There may be other methods, however.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE statement inside the COUNT() window function.  Since count doesn't increment if the value is NULL you can use this to exclude the values you don't want.  When embedding a CASE() statement like this and when it is simple I like to use DECODE() as it is more compact and readable.

Something like this (sorry I don't have a cluster in front of my right now so apologies if I have a typo):

```
count(DECODE(date_issued < getdate() - interval '120 days', true, invoice_id, NULL)) OVER(PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY date_issued rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as invoices
```